# How to monitor the performance of a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, google-chrome

In Chrome, there is a Performance tab in Dev Tools which seems to give you all the information you need about how functions are performing.

It has useful info like how long they took to run, memory, etc.

The issue is it doesn't tell you the name of the function!

How can we work out what function it is talking about, in the Performance Tab.

It just says things like "Task took 300ms","Animation took x seconds", "HTML Request Frame..."

Doesn't it make sense to include the name of the function?

How can we work this out

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know in-depth, [check this out](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance). The tutorial explains in-depth how to measure performance and bottlenecks in your webpage.